# Sets cardinality in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let's suppose that $S$ and $T$ are sets, $S$ is finite, cardinality of $T$ is larger than that of $S$ (include the possibility where T could be an infinite set), Then, define $f: \mathbb{R}\langle T\rangle \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\langle S\rangle $ is a linear map. Show that $kerf \neq 0$.

My approach to the problem reduces to $T$ being finite. Then, when I tried the case of $T$ being infinite I tried to define a bijection to polynomials (where I proved something similar) , but I didn't succeed. Do you have any ideas in how to proceed. Thanks

Comment: Could you define $\mathbb R \langle T \rangle$, please? (Maybe it's some standard notation, but I'm not familiar with it.)

Comment: @Stefan Yeah sure, it means linear combinations of $T$ with scalars in $\mathbb{R}$, is not the span by definition but something like that. We did define a linear map from $\mathbb{R}\langle T \rangle$ to Span($T$) which is a bijection. Sorry, my professor's notation is really messy.

Comment: Do you know how to do this if $T$ is finite? (It is unclear what you mean by "reduces to $T$ being finite".)

Comment: @EricWofsey $T$ and $S$ are the basis of  $\mathbb{R}\langle T\rangle$ and $\mathbb{R}\langle S\rangle$. I just applied Dimension Theorem, but that's not the case with infinite sets. Sorry again, but notation is also really hard for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $T'\subseteq T$ is any subset, then $\mathbb{R}\langle T'\rangle$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}\langle T\rangle$, and you can restrict the map $f$ to a linear map $\mathbb{R}\langle T'\rangle\to \mathbb{R}\langle S\rangle$.  So if $T$ is infinite, you can reduce to the finite case by choosing $T'$ to be any finite subset of $T$ that has more elements than $S$.

Answer (score 0):

A very fundamental theorem in Linear Algebra (the "Rank-Nullity theorem):
  If f is a linear transformation from S to T, K is the kernel of f (the set of all s in S such that f(s)= 0) and I is the image of f (the set of all t in T such there exist s in S with f(s)= t) then dim(K)+ dim(I)= dim(T).

Comment: $T$ could be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, what you have is a linear transformation $f\colon V\to W$ between vector spaces over $\mathbb R$ (or any other field for that matter), and it is given that the dimension of $V$ is larger than the dimension of $W$. You may find it easier to prove the more general claim that any such linear transformation must have a non-trivial kernel. The rank-nullity theorem works fine with infinite cardinalities.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you're saying.

Comment: you are drowning yourself in irrelevant details and so I threw you a lifeline. The fact that $V=\mathbb R\langle T\rangle$ and that $W=\mathbb R\langle S\rangle$ is quite irrelevant. The only thing that matters here are the dimensions.